# Getting real time statistics in Omnet++

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet

In:

https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part5/

and

https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:declaring-statistics

it's shown how network statistics can be processed after a simulation.

Is it possible to get network parameters dynamically?

Comment: How do you want to obtain these statistics during the simulation? Should they be printed in log?

Comment: No, I need to compute a number of values based on statistics (e.g. packets sent/packets received) and compare them to thresholds (they should be available in handleMessage()). Network behavior should change on the fly depending on these values (e.g. lower injection rate if loss is too high, etc.)

Comment: Do you need data from other modules to calculate a metric?

Comment: Yes, the modules are nodes in a wsn network (updated question).Each node should record one of the following: a packet created, a packet consumed (received), a packet forwarded, a packet corrupted.

Comment: @JerzyD. I've read about signals https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:signal-listeners but can't find any examples on how to implement them. Do you know of any related code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Use signals (not statistics) and hook up your own simple module on these signals and compute the required statistics in that module.

You cannot access the value of `@statistics` in your code, and there is a reason for this as this would be an *anti pattern*. NED based statistics were introduced as a method to add calculations and measurements to your model **without** modifying your models behavior and code. This means that statistics are NOT considered part of a model, but rather they are considered as a *configuration*. Changing a statistics (i.e. deciding that you want to measure something else) should never change the behavior of your model. That's why the actual value of a given statistic is not exposed (easily) to the C++ code. You could dig them out, but it is highly discouraged.

Now, this does not mean that what you want to achieve is not legitimate but the actual statistics gathering must be an integral part of your model. I.e. you should not aim for using built-in statistics, but rather create an **explicit** statistics gathering submodule that should hook up on the necessary signals (https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:subscribing-to-signals) and do the actual statistics computation you need in its C++ code. After that, other modules are free to access this information and make decisions based on that.

Comment: Thanks! Found out about signals/listeners Yesterday. Now I'm struggling to create packets that are forwarded to the application layer. UdpBasicApp packets are routed at the transport layer and don't make it all the way up to the application layer. I've asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201574/packets-created-in-udpbasicapp-are-not-forwarded-past-the-transport-ipv4-layer